# "Fatal message conversion error" when receiving JSON with Spring RabbitMQ

Tags: json, spring, spring-boot, spring-rabbit

I'm trying to setup synchronisation between two Spring applications with their own DBs. I need one table synchronised between them.

```
@Configuration
public class ConfigureRabbitMq {

public static final String QUEUE_NAME = "testqueue";
public static final String EXCHANGE_NAME = "testexchange";

@Bean
Queue createQueue(){
    return new Queue(QUEUE_NAME, false);
}

@Bean
TopicExchange exchange(){
    return new TopicExchange(EXCHANGE_NAME);
}

@Bean
Binding binding(Queue q, TopicExchange exchange){
    return BindingBuilder.bind(q).to(exchange).with("test.#");
}

@Bean
public RabbitTemplate rabbitTemplate(final ConnectionFactory connectionFactory) {
    final RabbitTemplate rabbitTemplate = new RabbitTemplate(connectionFactory);
    rabbitTemplate.setMessageConverter(producerJackson2MessageConverter());
    return rabbitTemplate;
}

@Bean
public Jackson2JsonMessageConverter producerJackson2MessageConverter() {
    return new Jackson2JsonMessageConverter();
}
}
```

And my Controller for sendMessage testing:

```
@RestController
public class SendMessageController {

private final RabbitTemplate rabbitTemplate;

public SendMessageController(RabbitTemplate rabbitTemplate) {
    this.rabbitTemplate = rabbitTemplate;
}

@PostMapping("/send/{value}")
public String sendMessage(@PathVariable String value){

    TestModel testModel = new TestModel("Gruppe 1");
    TestSubModel testSubModel = new TestSubModel("Ryan", 21, "IT", 3);
    TestSubModel testSubModel2 = new TestSubModel("Alex", 21, "DATA", 3);
    TestSubModel testSubModel3 = new TestSubModel("Rejwan", 22, "IT", 3);

    testModel.getTestSubModels().add(testSubModel);
    testModel.getTestSubModels().add(testSubModel2);
    testModel.getTestSubModels().add(testSubModel3);

    rabbitTemplate.convertAndSend(ConfigureRabbitMq.EXCHANGE_NAME, "test.springmessages", testModel);

    //rabbitTemplate.convertAndSend(ConfigureRabbitMq.EXCHANGE_NAME, "test.springmessages", value);
    return "We have sent a message: " + value;
}
}
```

Models I'm trying to send:

```
public class TestModel implements Serializable {
private String groupName;

private List<TestSubModel> testSubModels;

public TestModel(String groupName) {
    this.groupName = groupName;
    testSubModels = new ArrayList<>();
}

public String getGroupName() {
    return groupName;
}

public void setGroupName(String groupName) {
    this.groupName = groupName;
}

public List<TestSubModel> getTestSubModels() {
    return testSubModels;
}

public void setTestSubModels(List<TestSubModel> testSubModels) {
    this.testSubModels = testSubModels;
}
}
```

And:

```
package com.bachelor2020.chat;

import java.io.Serializable;

public class TestSubModel implements Serializable {

private String name;
private int age;
private String fieldOfStudy;
private int yearOfStudy;

public TestSubModel(String name, int age, String fieldOfStudy, int yearOfStudy) {
    this.name = name;
    this.age = age;
    this.fieldOfStudy = fieldOfStudy;
    this.yearOfStudy = yearOfStudy;
}

public String getName() {
    return name;
}

public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}

public int getAge() {
    return age;
}

public void setAge(int age) {
    this.age = age;
}

public String getFieldOfStudy() {
    return fieldOfStudy;
}

public void setFieldOfStudy(String fieldOfStudy) {
    this.fieldOfStudy = fieldOfStudy;
}

public int getYearOfStudy() {
    return yearOfStudy;
}

public void setYearOfStudy(int yearOfStudy) {
    this.yearOfStudy = yearOfStudy;
}
}
```

Service for receiving messages in the other application:

```
@Service
public class ReceiveMessageService {

public void handleMessage(Message message){
    System.out.println("HandleMessage: ");
    System.out.println(message.toString());
    System.out.println(message);
}
}
```

I get these errors:

```
2020-04-03 15:25:41.574  WARN 3293 --- [    container-1] ingErrorHandler$DefaultExceptionStrategy : Fatal message conversion error; message rejected; it will be dropped or routed to a dead letter exchange, if so configured: (Body:'{"groupName":"Gruppe 1","testSubModels":[{"name":"Ryan","age":21,"fieldOfStudy":"IT","yearOfStudy":3},{"name":"Alex","age":21,"fieldOfStudy":"DATA","yearOfStudy":3},{"name":"Rejwan","age":22,"fieldOfStudy":"IT","yearOfStudy":3}]}' MessageProperties [headers={__TypeId__=com.bachelor.rabbitmqdemo.TestModel}, contentType=application/json, contentEncoding=UTF-8, contentLength=0, receivedDeliveryMode=PERSISTENT, priority=0, redelivered=false, receivedExchange=testexchange, receivedRoutingKey=test.springmessages, deliveryTag=1, consumerTag=amq.ctag-FzEtStGEJs6xfGoux7_55Q, consumerQueue=testqueue])

2020-04-03 15:25:41.575 ERROR 3293 --- [    container-1] o.s.a.r.l.SimpleMessageListenerContainer : Execution of Rabbit message listener failed, and the error handler threw an exception
```

I have tested and confirmed that just sending simple Strings works, but I just can't seem to figure out how to parse the JSON message. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Edit:

This is my configuration on the receiving end. This app will only listen, never send any messages.

```
import org.springframework.amqp.core.Binding;
import org.springframework.amqp.core.BindingBuilder;
import org.springframework.amqp.core.Queue;
import org.springframework.amqp.core.TopicExchange;
import org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.connection.ConnectionFactory;
import org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.SimpleMessageListenerContainer;
import org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.adapter.MessageListenerAdapter;
import org.springframework.amqp.support.converter.Jackson2JsonMessageConverter;
import org.springframework.amqp.support.converter.MessageConverter;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;

@Configuration
public class ConfigureRabbitMq {

    public static final String QUEUE_NAME = "testqueue";
    public static final String EXCHANGE_NAME = "testexchange";

    @Bean
    Queue createQueue(){
        return new Queue(QUEUE_NAME, false);
    }

    @Bean
    TopicExchange exchange(){
        return new TopicExchange(EXCHANGE_NAME);
    }

    @Bean
    Binding binding(Queue q, TopicExchange exchange){
        return BindingBuilder.bind(q).to(exchange).with("test.#");
    }


    @Bean
    SimpleMessageListenerContainer container(ConnectionFactory connectionFactory, MessageListenerAdapter messageListenerAdapter){
        SimpleMessageListenerContainer container = new SimpleMessageListenerContainer();
        container.setConnectionFactory(connectionFactory);
        container.setQueueNames(QUEUE_NAME);
        container.setMessageListener(messageListenerAdapter);
        return container;
    }

    @Bean
    MessageListenerAdapter listenerAdapter(ReceiveMessageService service){
        return new MessageListenerAdapter(service, "handleMessage");
    }

    @Bean
    public MessageConverter jsonMessageConverter() {
        return new Jackson2JsonMessageConverter();
    }
}
```

EDIT:
Stacktrace

```
2020-04-03 19:01:55.481  WARN 8783 --- [    container-1] s.a.r.l.ConditionalRejectingErrorHandler : Execution of Rabbit message listener failed.

org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.support.ListenerExecutionFailedException: Failed to invoke target method 'handleMessage' with argument type = [class [B], value = [{[B@725344ff}]
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.adapter.MessageListenerAdapter.invokeListenerMethod(MessageListenerAdapter.java:405) ~[spring-rabbit-2.2.5.RELEASE.jar:2.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.adapter.MessageListenerAdapter.onMessage(MessageListenerAdapter.java:293) ~[spring-rabbit-2.2.5.RELEASE.jar:2.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.AbstractMessageListenerContainer.doInvokeListener(AbstractMessageListenerContainer.java:1579) ~[spring-rabbit-2.2.5.RELEASE.jar:2.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.AbstractMessageListenerContainer.actualInvokeListener(AbstractMessageListenerContainer.java:1498) ~[spring-rabbit-2.2.5.RELEASE.jar:2.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.AbstractMessageListenerContainer.invokeListener(AbstractMessageListenerContainer.java:1486) ~[spring-rabbit-2.2.5.RELEASE.jar:2.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.AbstractMessageListenerContainer.doExecuteListener(AbstractMessageListenerContainer.java:1477) ~[spring-rabbit-2.2.5.RELEASE.jar:2.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.AbstractMessageListenerContainer.executeListener(AbstractMessageListenerContainer.java:1421) ~[spring-rabbit-2.2.5.RELEASE.jar:2.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.SimpleMessageListenerContainer.doReceiveAndExecute(SimpleMessageListenerContainer.java:963) [spring-rabbit-2.2.5.RELEASE.jar:2.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.SimpleMessageListenerContainer.receiveAndExecute(SimpleMessageListenerContainer.java:913) [spring-rabbit-2.2.5.RELEASE.jar:2.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.SimpleMessageListenerContainer.access$1600(SimpleMessageListenerContainer.java:81) [spring-rabbit-2.2.5.RELEASE.jar:2.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.SimpleMessageListenerContainer$AsyncMessageProcessingConsumer.mainLoop(SimpleMessageListenerContainer.java:1284) [spring-rabbit-2.2.5.RELEASE.jar:2.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.SimpleMessageListenerContainer$AsyncMessageProcessingConsumer.run(SimpleMessageListenerContainer.java:1190) [spring-rabbit-2.2.5.RELEASE.jar:2.2.5.RELEASE]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748) [na:1.8.0_144]
Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: com.bachelor2020.chat.consumer.ReceiveMessageService.handleMessage([B)
    at java.lang.Class.getMethod(Class.java:1786) ~[na:1.8.0_144]
    at org.springframework.util.MethodInvoker.prepare(MethodInvoker.java:184) ~[spring-core-5.2.5.RELEASE.jar:5.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.adapter.MessageListenerAdapter.invokeListenerMethod(MessageListenerAdapter.java:383) ~[spring-rabbit-2.2.5.RELEASE.jar:2.2.5.RELEASE]
    ... 12 common frames omitted

2020-04-03 19:01:55.482  WARN 8783 --- [    container-1] ingErrorHandler$DefaultExceptionStrategy : Fatal message conversion error; message rejected; it will be dropped or routed to a dead letter exchange, if so configured: (Body:'{"groupName":"Gruppe 1","testSubModels":[{"name":"Ryan","age":21,"fieldOfStudy":"IT","yearOfStudy":3},{"name":"Alex","age":21,"fieldOfStudy":"DATA","yearOfStudy":3},{"name":"Rejwan","age":22,"fieldOfStudy":"IT","yearOfStudy":3}]}' MessageProperties [headers={__TypeId__=com.bachelor.rabbitmqdemo.TestModel}, contentType=application/json, contentEncoding=UTF-8, contentLength=0, receivedDeliveryMode=PERSISTENT, priority=0, redelivered=false, receivedExchange=testexchange, receivedRoutingKey=test.springmessages, deliveryTag=3, consumerTag=amq.ctag-GdT0qUHVnRO-5m9neFNM6Q, consumerQueue=testqueue])
2020-04-03 19:01:55.482 ERROR 8783 --- [    container-1] o.s.a.r.l.SimpleMessageListenerContainer : Execution of Rabbit message listener failed, and the error handler threw an exception

org.springframework.amqp.AmqpRejectAndDontRequeueException: Error Handler converted exception to fatal
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.ConditionalRejectingErrorHandler.handleError(ConditionalRejectingErrorHandler.java:116) ~[spring-rabbit-2.2.5.RELEASE.jar:2.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.AbstractMessageListenerContainer.invokeErrorHandler(AbstractMessageListenerContainer.java:1383) [spring-rabbit-2.2.5.RELEASE.jar:2.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.AbstractMessageListenerContainer.handleListenerException(AbstractMessageListenerContainer.java:1667) [spring-rabbit-2.2.5.RELEASE.jar:2.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.AbstractMessageListenerContainer.executeListener(AbstractMessageListenerContainer.java:1442) [spring-rabbit-2.2.5.RELEASE.jar:2.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.SimpleMessageListenerContainer.doReceiveAndExecute(SimpleMessageListenerContainer.java:963) [spring-rabbit-2.2.5.RELEASE.jar:2.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.SimpleMessageListenerContainer.receiveAndExecute(SimpleMessageListenerContainer.java:913) [spring-rabbit-2.2.5.RELEASE.jar:2.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.SimpleMessageListenerContainer.access$1600(SimpleMessageListenerContainer.java:81) [spring-rabbit-2.2.5.RELEASE.jar:2.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.SimpleMessageListenerContainer$AsyncMessageProcessingConsumer.mainLoop(SimpleMessageListenerContainer.java:1284) [spring-rabbit-2.2.5.RELEASE.jar:2.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.SimpleMessageListenerContainer$AsyncMessageProcessingConsumer.run(SimpleMessageListenerContainer.java:1190) [spring-rabbit-2.2.5.RELEASE.jar:2.2.5.RELEASE]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748) [na:1.8.0_144]
Caused by: org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.support.ListenerExecutionFailedException: Failed to invoke target method 'handleMessage' with argument type = [class [B], value = [{[B@725344ff}]
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.adapter.MessageListenerAdapter.invokeListenerMethod(MessageListenerAdapter.java:405) ~[spring-rabbit-2.2.5.RELEASE.jar:2.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.adapter.MessageListenerAdapter.onMessage(MessageListenerAdapter.java:293) ~[spring-rabbit-2.2.5.RELEASE.jar:2.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.AbstractMessageListenerContainer.doInvokeListener(AbstractMessageListenerContainer.java:1579) [spring-rabbit-2.2.5.RELEASE.jar:2.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.AbstractMessageListenerContainer.actualInvokeListener(AbstractMessageListenerContainer.java:1498) [spring-rabbit-2.2.5.RELEASE.jar:2.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.AbstractMessageListenerContainer.invokeListener(AbstractMessageListenerContainer.java:1486) [spring-rabbit-2.2.5.RELEASE.jar:2.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.AbstractMessageListenerContainer.doExecuteListener(AbstractMessageListenerContainer.java:1477) [spring-rabbit-2.2.5.RELEASE.jar:2.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.AbstractMessageListenerContainer.executeListener(AbstractMessageListenerContainer.java:1421) [spring-rabbit-2.2.5.RELEASE.jar:2.2.5.RELEASE]
    ... 6 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: com.bachelor2020.chat.consumer.ReceiveMessageService.handleMessage([B)
    at java.lang.Class.getMethod(Class.java:1786) ~[na:1.8.0_144]
    at org.springframework.util.MethodInvoker.prepare(MethodInvoker.java:184) ~[spring-core-5.2.5.RELEASE.jar:5.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.adapter.MessageListenerAdapter.invokeListenerMethod(MessageListenerAdapter.java:383) ~[spring-rabbit-2.2.5.RELEASE.jar:2.2.5.RELEASE]
    ... 12 common frames omitted
```

EDIT:
I tried to actually set the jsonMessageConverter in the container bean, and got a different error

`messageListenerAdapter.setMessageConverter(jsonMessageConverter());`
in

```
@Bean
    SimpleMessageListenerContainer container(ConnectionFactory connectionFactory, MessageListenerAdapter messageListenerAdapter){
        SimpleMessageListenerContainer container = new SimpleMessageListenerContainer();
        container.setConnectionFactory(connectionFactory);
        container.setQueueNames(QUEUE_NAME);
        messageListenerAdapter.setMessageConverter(jsonMessageConverter());
        container.setMessageListener(messageListenerAdapter);
        return container;
    }
```

```
2020-04-03 19:30:15.718  WARN 21123 --- [    container-1] s.a.r.l.ConditionalRejectingErrorHandler : Execution of Rabbit message listener failed.

org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.support.ListenerExecutionFailedException: Listener threw exception
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.AbstractMessageListenerContainer.wrapToListenerExecutionFailedExceptionIfNeeded(AbstractMessageListenerContainer.java:1693) ~[spring-rabbit-2.2.5.RELEASE.jar:2.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.AbstractMessageListenerContainer.doInvokeListener(AbstractMessageListenerContainer.java:1583) ~[spring-rabbit-2.2.5.RELEASE.jar:2.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.AbstractMessageListenerContainer.actualInvokeListener(AbstractMessageListenerContainer.java:1498) ~[spring-rabbit-2.2.5.RELEASE.jar:2.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.AbstractMessageListenerContainer.invokeListener(AbstractMessageListenerContainer.java:1486) ~[spring-rabbit-2.2.5.RELEASE.jar:2.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.AbstractMessageListenerContainer.doExecuteListener(AbstractMessageListenerContainer.java:1477) ~[spring-rabbit-2.2.5.RELEASE.jar:2.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.AbstractMessageListenerContainer.executeListener(AbstractMessageListenerContainer.java:1421) ~[spring-rabbit-2.2.5.RELEASE.jar:2.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.SimpleMessageListenerContainer.doReceiveAndExecute(SimpleMessageListenerContainer.java:963) [spring-rabbit-2.2.5.RELEASE.jar:2.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.SimpleMessageListenerContainer.receiveAndExecute(SimpleMessageListenerContainer.java:913) [spring-rabbit-2.2.5.RELEASE.jar:2.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.SimpleMessageListenerContainer.access$1600(SimpleMessageListenerContainer.java:81) [spring-rabbit-2.2.5.RELEASE.jar:2.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.SimpleMessageListenerContainer$AsyncMessageProcessingConsumer.mainLoop(SimpleMessageListenerContainer.java:1284) [spring-rabbit-2.2.5.RELEASE.jar:2.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.SimpleMessageListenerContainer$AsyncMessageProcessingConsumer.run(SimpleMessageListenerContainer.java:1190) [spring-rabbit-2.2.5.RELEASE.jar:2.2.5.RELEASE]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748) [na:1.8.0_144]
Caused by: org.springframework.amqp.support.converter.MessageConversionException: failed to resolve class name. Class not found [com.bachelor.rabbitmqdemo.TestModel]
    at org.springframework.amqp.support.converter.DefaultJackson2JavaTypeMapper.getClassIdType(DefaultJackson2JavaTypeMapper.java:178) ~[spring-amqp-2.2.5.RELEASE.jar:2.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.amqp.support.converter.DefaultJackson2JavaTypeMapper.fromTypeHeader(DefaultJackson2JavaTypeMapper.java:135) ~[spring-amqp-2.2.5.RELEASE.jar:2.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.amqp.support.converter.DefaultJackson2JavaTypeMapper.toJavaType(DefaultJackson2JavaTypeMapper.java:124) ~[spring-amqp-2.2.5.RELEASE.jar:2.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.amqp.support.converter.AbstractJackson2MessageConverter.doFromMessage(AbstractJackson2MessageConverter.java:291) ~[spring-amqp-2.2.5.RELEASE.jar:2.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.amqp.support.converter.AbstractJackson2MessageConverter.fromMessage(AbstractJackson2MessageConverter.java:259) ~[spring-amqp-2.2.5.RELEASE.jar:2.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.amqp.support.converter.AbstractJackson2MessageConverter.fromMessage(AbstractJackson2MessageConverter.java:239) ~[spring-amqp-2.2.5.RELEASE.jar:2.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.adapter.AbstractAdaptableMessageListener.extractMessage(AbstractAdaptableMessageListener.java:302) ~[spring-rabbit-2.2.5.RELEASE.jar:2.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.adapter.MessageListenerAdapter.onMessage(MessageListenerAdapter.java:283) ~[spring-rabbit-2.2.5.RELEASE.jar:2.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.AbstractMessageListenerContainer.doInvokeListener(AbstractMessageListenerContainer.java:1579) ~[spring-rabbit-2.2.5.RELEASE.jar:2.2.5.RELEASE]
    ... 10 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.bachelor.rabbitmqdemo.TestModel
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381) ~[na:1.8.0_144]
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424) ~[na:1.8.0_144]
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:335) ~[na:1.8.0_144]
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357) ~[na:1.8.0_144]
    at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_144]
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:348) ~[na:1.8.0_144]
    at org.springframework.util.ClassUtils.forName(ClassUtils.java:285) ~[spring-core-5.2.5.RELEASE.jar:5.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.amqp.support.converter.DefaultJackson2JavaTypeMapper.getClassIdType(DefaultJackson2JavaTypeMapper.java:174) ~[spring-amqp-2.2.5.RELEASE.jar:2.2.5.RELEASE]
    ... 18 common frames omitted

2020-04-03 19:30:15.718  WARN 21123 --- [    container-1] ingErrorHandler$DefaultExceptionStrategy : Fatal message conversion error; message rejected; it will be dropped or routed to a dead letter exchange, if so configured: (Body:'{"groupName":"Gruppe 1","testSubModels":[{"name":"Ryan","age":21,"fieldOfStudy":"IT","yearOfStudy":3},{"name":"Alex","age":21,"fieldOfStudy":"DATA","yearOfStudy":3},{"name":"Rejwan","age":22,"fieldOfStudy":"IT","yearOfStudy":3}]}' MessageProperties [headers={__TypeId__=com.bachelor.rabbitmqdemo.TestModel}, contentType=application/json, contentEncoding=UTF-8, contentLength=0, receivedDeliveryMode=PERSISTENT, priority=0, redelivered=false, receivedExchange=testexchange, receivedRoutingKey=test.springmessages, deliveryTag=2, consumerTag=amq.ctag-MU3vtzsW8ikgTqCRoc6YGw, consumerQueue=testqueue])
2020-04-03 19:30:15.719 ERROR 21123 --- [    container-1] o.s.a.r.l.SimpleMessageListenerContainer : Execution of Rabbit message listener failed, and the error handler threw an exception

org.springframework.amqp.AmqpRejectAndDontRequeueException: Error Handler converted exception to fatal
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.ConditionalRejectingErrorHandler.handleError(ConditionalRejectingErrorHandler.java:116) ~[spring-rabbit-2.2.5.RELEASE.jar:2.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.AbstractMessageListenerContainer.invokeErrorHandler(AbstractMessageListenerContainer.java:1383) [spring-rabbit-2.2.5.RELEASE.jar:2.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.AbstractMessageListenerContainer.handleListenerException(AbstractMessageListenerContainer.java:1667) [spring-rabbit-2.2.5.RELEASE.jar:2.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.AbstractMessageListenerContainer.executeListener(AbstractMessageListenerContainer.java:1442) [spring-rabbit-2.2.5.RELEASE.jar:2.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.SimpleMessageListenerContainer.doReceiveAndExecute(SimpleMessageListenerContainer.java:963) [spring-rabbit-2.2.5.RELEASE.jar:2.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.SimpleMessageListenerContainer.receiveAndExecute(SimpleMessageListenerContainer.java:913) [spring-rabbit-2.2.5.RELEASE.jar:2.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.SimpleMessageListenerContainer.access$1600(SimpleMessageListenerContainer.java:81) [spring-rabbit-2.2.5.RELEASE.jar:2.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.SimpleMessageListenerContainer$AsyncMessageProcessingConsumer.mainLoop(SimpleMessageListenerContainer.java:1284) [spring-rabbit-2.2.5.RELEASE.jar:2.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.SimpleMessageListenerContainer$AsyncMessageProcessingConsumer.run(SimpleMessageListenerContainer.java:1190) [spring-rabbit-2.2.5.RELEASE.jar:2.2.5.RELEASE]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748) [na:1.8.0_144]
Caused by: org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.support.ListenerExecutionFailedException: Listener threw exception
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.AbstractMessageListenerContainer.wrapToListenerExecutionFailedExceptionIfNeeded(AbstractMessageListenerContainer.java:1693) [spring-rabbit-2.2.5.RELEASE.jar:2.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.AbstractMessageListenerContainer.doInvokeListener(AbstractMessageListenerContainer.java:1583) [spring-rabbit-2.2.5.RELEASE.jar:2.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.AbstractMessageListenerContainer.actualInvokeListener(AbstractMessageListenerContainer.java:1498) [spring-rabbit-2.2.5.RELEASE.jar:2.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.AbstractMessageListenerContainer.invokeListener(AbstractMessageListenerContainer.java:1486) [spring-rabbit-2.2.5.RELEASE.jar:2.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.AbstractMessageListenerContainer.doExecuteListener(AbstractMessageListenerContainer.java:1477) [spring-rabbit-2.2.5.RELEASE.jar:2.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.AbstractMessageListenerContainer.executeListener(AbstractMessageListenerContainer.java:1421) [spring-rabbit-2.2.5.RELEASE.jar:2.2.5.RELEASE]
    ... 6 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.springframework.amqp.support.converter.MessageConversionException: failed to resolve class name. Class not found [com.bachelor.rabbitmqdemo.TestModel]
    at org.springframework.amqp.support.converter.DefaultJackson2JavaTypeMapper.getClassIdType(DefaultJackson2JavaTypeMapper.java:178) ~[spring-amqp-2.2.5.RELEASE.jar:2.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.amqp.support.converter.DefaultJackson2JavaTypeMapper.fromTypeHeader(DefaultJackson2JavaTypeMapper.java:135) ~[spring-amqp-2.2.5.RELEASE.jar:2.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.amqp.support.converter.DefaultJackson2JavaTypeMapper.toJavaType(DefaultJackson2JavaTypeMapper.java:124) ~[spring-amqp-2.2.5.RELEASE.jar:2.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.amqp.support.converter.AbstractJackson2MessageConverter.doFromMessage(AbstractJackson2MessageConverter.java:291) ~[spring-amqp-2.2.5.RELEASE.jar:2.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.amqp.support.converter.AbstractJackson2MessageConverter.fromMessage(AbstractJackson2MessageConverter.java:259) ~[spring-amqp-2.2.5.RELEASE.jar:2.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.amqp.support.converter.AbstractJackson2MessageConverter.fromMessage(AbstractJackson2MessageConverter.java:239) ~[spring-amqp-2.2.5.RELEASE.jar:2.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.adapter.AbstractAdaptableMessageListener.extractMessage(AbstractAdaptableMessageListener.java:302) ~[spring-rabbit-2.2.5.RELEASE.jar:2.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.adapter.MessageListenerAdapter.onMessage(MessageListenerAdapter.java:283) ~[spring-rabbit-2.2.5.RELEASE.jar:2.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.AbstractMessageListenerContainer.doInvokeListener(AbstractMessageListenerContainer.java:1579) [spring-rabbit-2.2.5.RELEASE.jar:2.2.5.RELEASE]
    ... 10 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.bachelor.rabbitmqdemo.TestModel
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381) ~[na:1.8.0_144]
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424) ~[na:1.8.0_144]
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:335) ~[na:1.8.0_144]
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357) ~[na:1.8.0_144]
    at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_144]
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:348) ~[na:1.8.0_144]
    at org.springframework.util.ClassUtils.forName(ClassUtils.java:285) ~[spring-core-5.2.5.RELEASE.jar:5.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.amqp.support.converter.DefaultJackson2JavaTypeMapper.getClassIdType(DefaultJackson2JavaTypeMapper.java:174) ~[spring-amqp-2.2.5.RELEASE.jar:2.2.5.RELEASE]
    ... 18 common frames omitted
```

I see that there is an error with the consumer app not having the same classpath. How can I solve this?

Comment: What is your listener container configuration? Do you supply it with similar `Jackson2JsonMessageConverter`? Is there a guarantee that your `TestModel` is present on the listener classpath?

Comment: @ArtemBilan I updated my question with the configuration for the app that listens to message. Not sure what you mean with if there is a guarantee that my TestModel is present on the listener classpath though, could you elaborate?

Comment: You need to show the full stack trace.

Comment: You a `jsonMessageConverter()` bean, but it is out of use. Typically producer and consumer are separate applications with their own classpath. To be able to convert incoming JSON into an expected type in the headers you definitely have to have that class on consumer classpath. Also with the `MessageListenerAdapter` there is no any conversions. So, you indeed have to show us more logs.

Comment: @ArtemBilan added the full stack trace now. I do have producer and consumer as separate applications. They both have the exact same TestModel and TestSubModel classes. Also with the jsonMessageConverter(), I thought since it was a bean, Spring would auto configure to use it when receiving messages, but I don't remember where I read that so I might be wrong

Comment: Please, read your stack trace: `java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.bachelor.rabbitmqdemo.TestModel`. So, it's not true that your consumer has that class available...

Comment: Yeah... I thought having a same class with the same name would work heh. Any ideas how I can solve this?

Comment: Well, you need to make yourself familiar what is classpath in Java. Your `TestModel` class has to be copied into a consumer application or you should have it in the shared jar.

Comment: How can we solve this issue?